# Can this Kitchen Art Non Fry Pan, made in South Korea, be seasoned?

Tags: seasoning-pans

Today is my first time learning about [seasoning pans](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/97151). Doubtless, ["season" here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/91173) doesn't signify "Add salt, herbs, pepper, or other spices to (food)".

1. What kind of pan is [Kitchen Art, Professional Nonstick Fry Pan/Dishwasher Safe Cookware, 30 cm](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01E8OHA1U)? It's made in South Korea. [Chowhound has a thread](https://www.chowhound.com/post/kitchen-art-stick-pans-galleria-moved-ontario-board-792306).

Or is it [Carbon Steel](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/42872), [Cast Al](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/63330), [cast iron](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/20249) [Mineral B](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/56998), [Teflon-coated stainless steel](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/44513), etc...?

[image]

2. Can it be perfectly seasoned or restored? Ought a new better one be purchased?

[image]

[image]

They've been using this pan purchased merely 1 year ago for [all their foods](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/29606), partly to shun washing multiple pans. They thought that with 2020 technology, cast iron pans can support [liquids](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/11772) and [sauces](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/11547) of any pH level. They always turn heat to the maximum.

Six days ago, they noticed that their pan's bottom was uneven, blemished, and no longer non-stick. When they scratched its bottom gently with their fingernail, black smut/soot comes off and adheres to their fingernails.

Answer (score 3):

Your link says “non-stick coating” and “aluminum”. When said coating is damaged or worn down, you have to discard the pan. This is just how these pans are, they aren’t made to last for generations like cast iron (which would be significantly heavier, btw).

You can’t create a polymerized oils seasoning on top of a non-stick layer and even if you sanded down the remaining coating, the bare aluminum wouldn’t be “seasonable”.

Answer (score 2):

[Re-seasoning](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/91173/45339) is a process done on cast iron or carbon steel pans to build a coating that makes the cooking surface usable. This **is not** cast iron.

Based on the updated info when the brand, it is an aluminum pan with a nonstick coating. Unlike cast iron or carbon steel, these cannot be reseasoned. When the nonstick coating is damaged, you throw it away and replace it.

It looks like this pan has some damage to the cooking surface--there's a large spot that is lighter color where the coating may have peeled away. That isn't repairable, and the pan would need to be replaced. It also looks like this pan may just need a good washing--some of the buildup may just be stuck on food that has burned/carbonized.

Comment: Thank you! I added more details to my post. Do they change your answer?